# document.lastModified only displays current date?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for a way to display the date the page last was updated.

Now I've been searching around, and everything points to the document.lastModified function, but however I've tried to fix it, it always shows the current date.

I've tried this example:

```
function lastModified() { 
var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified); 
var showAs = modiDate.getDate() + "-" + (modiDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + modiDate.getFullYear(); 
return showAs
 }
 function GetTime() {
 var modiDate = new Date(); 
var Seconds 

if (modiDate.getSeconds() < 10) { 
Seconds = "0" + modiDate.getSeconds(); } 
else { 
Seconds = modiDate.getSeconds(); } 
var modiDate = new Date(); 
var CurTime = modiDate.getHours() + ":" + modiDate.getMinutes() + ":" + Seconds 
return CurTime } 

document.write("Last updated on ");
 document.write(lastModified() + " @ " + GetTime()); 
document.write(" [D M Y 24 Hour Clock]"); document.write("");
```

Or a simple one like this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
var t = new Date(document.lastModified);
document.write("<I>Last Updated: "+document.lastModified+"</I><BR>");
document.write("<I>Last Updated: "+t+"</I><BR>");
 </SCRIPT>
```

Is there any other way to do this?
.. Without taking a 3 years tech-class?

[Press here to see the scripts live](https://dropbox.wearenotalone.se/date.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are modifying it currently. Check this out for example.

To make this work based on your requirement, checkout [this link](http://Because%20you%20are%20modifying%20it%20currently.%20Check%20this%20out%20for%20example.%20%20To%20make%20this%20work%20based%20on%20your%20requirement,%20checkout%20this%20link%20and%20this%20link%20%20Copying%20from%20the%20external%20link:) and [this link](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-58508.html)

check this it will help u
Put this on the page at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_lus.js"></script>
 Name the file whatever you want. Example: js_lus.js Make sure src="" 
 path is correct for all your pages.
function lastModified() {
var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
var showAs = modiDate.getDate() + "-" + (modiDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + 
modiDate.getFullYear();
return showAs
}

function GetTime() {
var modiDate = new Date();
var Seconds

if (modiDate.getSeconds() < 10) {
    Seconds = "0" + modiDate.getSeconds();
} else {
    Seconds = modiDate.getSeconds();
}

var modiDate = new Date();
var CurTime = modiDate.getHours() + ":" + modiDate.getMinutes() + ":" + Seconds
return CurTime
}

document.write("Last updated on ")
document.write(lastModified() + " @ " + GetTime());
document.write(" [D M Y 24 Hour Clock]")
document.write("");
```

Comment: That is actually one of the script

Comment: have you check the links given above

Comment: Yes, what I can understand from that is that it's the servers fault?

Comment: try to debug or change  the server configuration settings

Comment: It's not my server, in only renting a space, however I just tried the javascript:alert(document.lastModified) on a Google page, and that also returned today's date and time..

Comment: the cmd document.lastmodified will won't work on sites where the page content is generated dynamically. These types of pages are, in effect, being modified with each visit, so this trick doesn't help in these cases.

Comment: Ah, that's a possibility, the host (one.com) must be using some kind of dynamic generator, well i might as well skip the script and update manually.. well, thx for the info..